# iOS .onContinueUserActivity Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsuseractivity

`.onContinueUserActivity` is never called in the [state restoration example app provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui).

Inside of DetailView, this method is called:

```
// The described activity for this view.
.userActivity(DetailView.productUserActivityType,
              isActive: product.id.uuidString == selectedProductID) { userActivity in
    describeUserActivity(userActivity)
}
```

Inside of ContentView (parent of DetailView), this method is NOT called:

```
.onContinueUserActivity(DetailView.productUserActivityType) { userActivity in
    if let product = try? userActivity.typedPayload(Product.self) {
        selectedProduct = product.id.uuidString
    }
}
```

I know `.onContinueUserActivity` is not being called by placing print statements in the method, and because commenting it out has no effect on the app's restoration.

The "Test State Restoration" strategies listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui) do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a case of sample code that doesn't work the way it's advertised. If you correctly test the app that's built from the sample code, it *does* restore state of the app, but not through the mechanism that they claim to be using.

You are correct. The `onContinueUserActivity` block isn't being called at all. You can remove that code from the app, and it continues to restore state in the way the NSUserActivity mechanism is supposed to. Further testing shows that it's just this line that's achieving the restoration:

```
@SceneStorage("ContentView.selectedProduct") private var selectedProduct: String?
```

That's a shame. I hope this gets sorted out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that this works on the Mac, so it is just a bug in iOS implementation, I think from iOS 16 onwards.

Comment: Interesting. I'd love to see this working in any context. What are you doing to get it to work on Mac? I downloaded a fresh copy, set the Team parameter is "Signing & Capabilities", then built and ran the app. I then chose "Mango" from the list of products, quit the app, and restarted. But it starts at the main products page, rather than going to the mango page. Does it do something different for you?

Comment: @CuriousJorge I haven't tried the sample at all, but this certainly calls .continueActivity unlike on iOS. And in my use case of Handoff implementation it shows on another device that there is the activity to continue. I am talking about the native Mac SwiftUI app, if you are using Catalyst then it is more likely to work the same as on iOS.

Comment: Ah. Yes, the app is set up with a destination of Mac (built for iPad), which I think means Catalyst. I don't know what it would take to reconfigure it to pure Mac SwiftUI app. So, unfortunately, the original poster's question on the sample app seems to remain that it doesn't work.