# How to get SwiftUI's .onContinueUserActivity working

Tags: ios, swiftui, nsuseractivity

I'm curious, has anyone managed to get SwiftUI's .onContinueUserActivity working? Looking at the [sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui), it seems to be working in their app (note the testing instructions in the ReadMe file). But when I set up a new project for myself and try to reproduce it, I can't get it to work.

Mine is just a vanilla SwiftUI project with the following changes:

1. In the info.plist, I have defined:

```
    <key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.example.RnD.customActivity</string>
    </array>
```

2. Here's my app definition:

```
@main
struct UserActivityDemoApp: App {
    static let customActivityType = "com.example.RnD.customActivity"
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .userActivity(Self.customActivityType, isActive: true) { activity in
                    activity.title = "Doing Custom Activity"
                    activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
                    activity.isEligibleForHandoff = true
                    activity.becomeCurrent()
                    print("Defining user activity")
                }
                .onContinueUserActivity(Self.customActivityType) { activity in
                    print("we should resume \(activity.title ?? "misconfigured activity")")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I would think this should be enough to get the "we should resume ..." message printed, but it isn't working. Is there something more I need to do in the `.userActivity` block? [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/creating_a_user_activity_object) seem to suggest that I have done enough.

Comment: Digging some more, I found [that it doesn't even work in the sample app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75598006/14840926), at least not by using NSUserActivity. So is this a dead-end for now?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it works from macOS, so it is likely a problem in their iOS implementation.